# How to Create a Doughnut chart in Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I want to create a doughnut chart something like this. Where can I find the appropriate tools or libraries?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Pick a package like chart.js: https://www.chartjs.org/
And you can implement it with a nested doughnut chart.

Comment: Worth noting there is an Angular wrapper for chart.js: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of options you can use them.
Fist one is `D3` is one of the most popular open-source library fro `Data visualization` and you can use it with Angular. See [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/data-visualization-angular-d3/)

[this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvzqdv) is a working example that I found it.

And [this](http://jsfiddle.net/joshvito/zjv8mq9k/) another working example with multi-ring

Other Angular-Based charts can be found [here](https://www.ngdevelop.tech/best-angular-chart-libraries/)